# DatePart(Quarter) with DateAdd not functioning

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am querying dates and pulling the quarters out. I have two queries that are similar. One is working while the other will not work.

Both queries need to pull out the quarter and list them as QEDD - I'm trying to compare show quarters and years for those quarters in my final report.

Working Query:

```
SELECT Sum(lm.Qty) as Proposed, lm.Entity as Entity, List = 'Spares', 
Year(DateAdd(Day,(lm.DeliveryARO + 90), GetDate())) AS YEDD, DatePart(Q, 
DateAdd(Day, (lm.DeliveryARO + 30), GetDate())) AS QEDD, lm.award, 
lm.PartNo, tb.tboid

FROM DBlm AS lm
Left Join DBtb as TB
ON lm.PartNo = tb.partno

WHERE lm.Entity = 'AAF' and lm.AwardDate is null and lm.award <>'Requirement Cancelled' and lm.ProposalDate is not null
GROUP BY Entity, DeliveryARO, award, lm.partno, tb.tboid, tb.partno
```

Not Working Query:

```
SELECT sum(rm.Qty) as Proposed, rm.Entity as Entity, List = 'ROR',
Case WHEN rm.itemstatus = 'Additional Repair Proposal Submitted – Pending Award' then Year(DateADD(Day, (rm.ivFinalDelvTerms + 60), GetDate())) END AS YEDD,
Case When rm.itemstatus = 'Repair Proposal Submitted - Pending Award' then DatePart(Q, DateAdd(Day, (rm.iiDelvTerms + rm.ivFinalDelvTerms +90), GetDate())) END AS QEDD,
rm.award, tb.partno, tb.tboid

FROM DBrm AS rm
Inner Join DBtm as TB
ON rm.PartNo = tb.partno

where rm.ItemStatus like '%pending%award%' and 
tb.PartNo = rm.PartNo and rm.Entity = 'AAF' 

Group By Entity, award, tb.tboid, tb.partno, rm.IIDelvTerms, 
rm.IVFinalDelvTerms, rm.itemstatus, rm.qty
```

This second query is returning the correct year or YEDD but the Quarter or QEDD returns as NULL. I have tried adjusting the equation as far as to remove one of my columns from the date add and it doesn't help.

I haven't found much of an instance of this happening anywhere else. I've seen people suggest casting to a string but the columns containing iiDelvTerms and FinalDelvTerms are already string format.

Any thoughts or suggestions on what my error maybe would be appreciated.

Sample Query results:

```
Proposed Entity List YEDD QEDD Award PartNo TBoId iiDelvTerms IVFinalDelvTerms
4         AAF   ROR 2018  NULL  M16 246     1        60        150
4         AAF   ROR 2018  NULL  M16 246     1        60        180
2         AAF   ROR 2018  NULL  M16 246     1        60        210
1         AAF   ROR 2018  NULL  M16 381     14       60        150
```

Comment: Since you don't have an `Else` to your `Case` statement, are you sure the `rm.itemstatus` meets the criteria to get the `QEDD`?

Comment: Yes - I'm getting single item returns for all of the items* based on the Where clause. I'ts just not calculating out the Quarters correctly.

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: I am assuming that rm.iiDelvTerms and rm.ivFinalDelvTerms are never null? Otherwise you would need to use ISNULL

Comment: Can you show the `rm.itemstatus` for the data? Validating that you are getting `rm.itemstatus = 'Repair Proposal Submitted - Pending Award'`

Comment: Correct, should never be NULL.

Comment: To verify I ran: When rm.itemstatus = '%Repair%Proposal%Submitted%Pending%Award%' then DatePart(Q, DateAdd(Day, (rm.iiDelvTerms + rm.ivFinalDelvTerms +90), GetDate())) END AS QEDD,

Also, I copy and pasted from my actual data table into the case statement to verify no mistakes in typing or hidden characters.

Comment: Simon can you elaborate on the ISNULL ? I do not believe the issue lies in itemstatus. I'm looking at alternate issues.